# Modal verb sentence order

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, modal-verb

I am learning German and we got our first modal verb today, können. We have to put the sentence in order. The sentence pieces are: Die Schüler/gut/Deutsch/können/? Is the sentence suppose to be 1.Können die Schüler gut Deutsch? or 2.Können die Schüler Deutsch gut?

Comment: If you're supposed to making sentences, why make questions?

Comment: Funny that in this sentence "können" is not used as as a modal verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are okay and they mean the same. There's a difference in tone. Or better, there's a difference in contextual appropriateness. That sounds very complicated but what I mean is simply that I think the second version is more likely in context where it has already been established verbally that the students speak German.
I think in beginners class they'd expect you to use version 1 but if they claim that it's the only correct way, tell them to read up again because it just ain't true.

EDIT:

Just to make sure... both are questions, not statements.

Comment: Ok thank you. That makes a lot more sense!